# WCF Service throwing exception as 401 on WCF Test Client and The provided URI scheme 'http' is invalid; expected 'https' during ASP.Net call

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

While working on WCF service I am facing some issue and receiving two different errors 
1. While accessing the service through WCFTectClient I am receiving Unauthorized error.
2. While accessing service through ASP.Net application using service reference I am receiving "The provided URI scheme 'http' is invalid; expected 'https'."

On my development environment everything is working perfectly fine however post hosting it is throwing errors. 
I tried matching and changing configuration settings in web.config but no use.

Below are my web.configs 
1. Service web.config

```
                <configuration>
              <system.web>
                <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
                <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
                <authentication mode="Windows" />
               <system.serviceModel>
                <client>
                  <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_SomeOtherClient" 
                  contract="SomeOtherClient_Contract}" name="BasicHttpBinding_SomeOtherClient" />
                  <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_SomeOtherClient1" contract=" 
               {SomeOtherClient_Contract1}" name="BasicHttpBinding_SomeOtherClient1" />
                </client>
                <bindings>
                  <basicHttpBinding>
                    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_MyName">
                      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
                      </security>
                    </binding>
                    </basicHttpBinding>
                </bindings>
                <services>
                  <service behaviorConfiguration="MEX" name="{SERVICE_CONFIGURATION_NAME}">
                    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_MyName" 
                    name="BasicHttpBinding_MyName" contract="MyService.Services.InterfaceName">
                      <identity>
                        <dns value="localhost" />
                      </identity>
                    </endpoint>
                    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" 
                contract="IMetadataExchange" />
                  </service>
                </services>
                <behaviors>
                  <serviceBehaviors>
                    <behavior name="MEX">
                      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"  />
                      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                      <serviceCredentials>
                        <clientCertificate>
                          <authentication mapClientCertificateToWindowsAccount="true" 
                  />
                        </clientCertificate>
                      </serviceCredentials>
                    </behavior>
                  </serviceBehaviors>
                   </behaviors>
                   <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" 
                  multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
                  </system.serviceModel>
                   </configuration>
```

2. Application Web.Config

   ```
               <configuration>
                 <system.web>
                   <browserCaps userAgentCacheKeyLength="256" />
                   <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2" />
                   <authentication mode="Windows" />
                   <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="20" />
                   <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID">
                   </pages>
                   <customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect="~/Error.aspx">
                   </customErrors>
                   <webServices>
                     <protocols>
                       <add name="HttpGet" />
                       <add name="HttpPost" />
                     </protocols>
                   </webServices>
                 </system.web>
                 <appSettings>
                    <add key="{WCF_SERVICE_URL}" value="http://ServerBaseURl/MyWCF_SERVICE_URL" />


                 </appSettings>
                 <system.serviceModel>
                   <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService="1" />
                   <behaviors>
                     <serviceBehaviors>
                       <behavior name="">
                         <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
                         <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                       </behavior>
                     </serviceBehaviors>
                   </behaviors>
                   <bindings>
                     <basicHttpBinding>
                       <binding openTimeout="01:50:00" receiveTimeout="01:50:00" sendTimeout="01:50:00" maxBufferPoolSize="20000000" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                         <readerQuotas maxDepth="128" maxStringContentLength="8388608" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                         <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
                           <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
                         </security>
                       </binding>

                         <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
                           <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
                         </security>
                       </binding>
                       <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_Windows" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                         <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
                           <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
                         </security>
                       </binding>
                       <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_MyName" receiveTimeout="00:20:00" sendTimeout="00:20:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                         <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
                           <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
                         </security>
                       </binding>


                     </basicHttpBinding>
                   </bindings>

               <client>
                       <endpoint address="MyServiceURL"
                     binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_MyName"
                      contract="yService.Services.InterfaceName"
                      name="BasicHttpBinding_MyName" />

                   </client>
                 </system.serviceModel>
                 <devExpress>
                   <settings rightToLeft="false" />
                   <compression enableHtmlCompression="false" enableCallbackCompression="true" enableResourceCompression="true" enableResourceMerging="true" />
                   <themes enableThemesAssembly="true" />
                   <errors callbackErrorRedirectUrl="" />
                 </devExpress>
               </configuration>
   ```

For WCF TestClient Below is the Exception

Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from {MyServiceURL} If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified address. For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to the MSDN documentation at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.WS-Metadata Exchange Error URI: {MyServiceURL} Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: '{MyServiceURL}'. The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate,NTLM'. The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.HTTP GET Error URI: {MyServiceURL} There was an error downloading '{MyServiceURL}'. The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.

For Application

The provided URI scheme 'http' is invalid; expected 'https'.
Parameter name: via 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]: The provided URI scheme 'http' is invalid; expected 'https'.
Parameter name: via

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[FaultException`1: The provided URI scheme 'http' is invalid; expected 'https'.
Parameter name: via]
   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) +14833358
   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type) +386

Comment: Probably your server is configured to allow http protocol in development mode. Try to change protocol in client configuration (change http to https):                 `<add key="{WCF_SERVICE_URL}" value="https://ServerBaseURl/MyWCF_SERVICE_URL" />`

Answer (score 0):

In the configuration file, the service is created by Basichttpbinding with TransportCredentialOnly security mode. and required client credential is windows. The first point requires that we need to specify an Http base address as a service base address. The second point is that we should specify a windows credential(username/password) when calling the service. this could not be achieved in Wcttestclient, except that we change the clientCredentialType.

```
<transport clientCredentialType="None"></transport>
```

As for the errors thrown by your application client. I suggest you generate the client proxy class by re-adding service reference.
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.

Comment: HI Abraham Qian Thanks for your reply.. However unfortunately still error exists

Comment: Are the errors thrown by the WCfTestclient? Can you access the SVC file in the browser properly when debugging the service? like this form,